# Разряды субстантивированных прилагательных по значению

Tags: морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, к какому разряду будут относиться выделенные субстантивированные И.П. - к отвлеченным или собирательным И.С.?

Он сразу узнавал *прекрасное* и *безобразное*, *истинное* и *ложное*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прекрасное и безобразное, истинное и ложное - это субстантивированные прилагательные, выражающие  абстрактные понятия. Собирательных прилагательных не бывает. Это **существительные делятся по тематическим разрядам на конкретные, отвлечённые, вещественные, собирательные.**

Среди  группы **субстантивных прилагательных** можно выделить следующие тематические группы: **Лицо** (военный, знакомый, нищий, ученый, лесничий). **Помещение** (учительская, ванная, проходная, операционная). **Лекарство** (слабительное, жаропонижающее, снотворное). **Документ** (дарственная, накладная). **Абстрактное понятие** (былое, прекрасное, достойный, прошлое.

Читайте подробнее на FB.ru: https://fb.ru/article/422082/substantivirovannyie-prilagatelnyie-i-ih-vidyi

Так что нужно решить, что это - существительное или прилагательное. Субстантивированное прилагательное - это прилагательное, выполняющее роль существительного в данном случае, но оно же может употребляться и как прилагательное в другом - прекрасное будущее, безобразное зрелище. Здесь это именно субстантивированное прилагательное, а не окончательно существительное.